# How to display content base on selected value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the content displayed on the screen when I select a value from a DropdownMenuItem which is populated with data from server.

I have been able to sync the server data with DropdownMenuItem.

My data is in this form;

```
 {
   "data":[
            {"id": 1, "country": "B"},
            {"id": 2, "country": "C"},
          ]
 }
```

So once I click on a value with index 1, the Screen should show content related to that value. For now, I show all data on the screeen.

How I sync my data

```
               items: item.map((value) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: value['id'].toString(),
                      child: new Text(value['name'])),
                }).toList()
```

I expect content to be displayed on the screen that pertains to the value selected on DropdownMenuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display content specific to the selected value, use the onChanged-function from [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Like in the code-sample mentioned, you get the newValue which is the selected value.
In this callback-function, you could just check, which content should be displayed and then you set the state.

```
onChanged: (String newValue) {
      setState(() {
        dropdownValue = newValue;
        contentToDisplay = Text(items[newValue]['country'])
      });
    },
```

The variable contentToDisplay would be a Widget defined in class, which you can build into the tree anywhere you want.

```
Scaffold(
   body: Column(
       children: [
           DropdownButton(...),
           Container(
               color: Colors.grey,
               child: contentToDisplay 
           )
       ]
   )
)
```

Comment: This is good buh newValue is of type String buh it should be an Integer. what should be the possible fix?

Comment: @Moplio the parameter given in the onChanged-callback is dynamic an is the same type as the one, the DropdownMenuItem has as value. Just change String newValue to int newValue